# Escaping Validation and sending form Data to email

Tags: php, html

i have online registeration form, i have done validation for it, but if i submit form without any data,i get validation errors and blank email will be sent to my mail.
**Any One Help Me Out**

Here is Form Code

```
<body>

<?php


// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $cnameErr = $mobilenoErr = $emailErr = $cityErr= $postalcodeErr = $addressErr = "";

$name = $cname = $mobileno = $email = $city= $postalcode = $address = "";

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $cname=$_POST['cname'];
    $mobileno=$_POST['mobileno'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $postalcode=$_POST['postalcode'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) { 
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["cname"])) {
     $cnameErr = "Company Name is required";
   } else {
     $cname = test_input($_POST["cname"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["mobileno"])) {
     $mobilenoErr = "Mobile Number is required";
   }else {
     $mobileno = test_input($_POST["mobileno"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[789][0-9]{9}$/",$mobileno)) {
       $mobilenoErr = "Not A Valid Number"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address is well-formed
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
     }
   }
   if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
     $cityErr = "City is required";
   }  else {
     $city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city)) {
       $cityErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }
   if (empty($_POST["postalcode"])) {
     $postalcodeErr = "Postal Code is required";
   } else {
     $postalcode = test_input($_POST["city"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
     $addressErr = "Address is required";
   } else {
     $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
 if(!empty($_POST['name'])&& !empty($_POST['cname'])&&!empty($_POST['mobileno'])&& !empty($_POST['email'])&&!empty($_POST['city'])&&!empty($_POST['postalcode'])&&!empty($_POST['address'])){
   header('Location: Submission.php?$submit=1');
   exit();}
$to = 'sskumbar7@gmail.com';

$subject = 'I need to show html'; 

$from ='sandeep.sk@microvillage.in'; 
ini_set("sendmail_from", $from);
$headers = "From: " .$from. "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from. "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;  charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $body ='User Name:'.$name.'<br>';
    $body .= 'Company Name:'.$cname.'<br>';
    $body .= 'Mobile Numbaer:'.$mobileno.'<br>';
    $body .= 'Email Id:'.$email.'<br>';
    $body .= 'City:'.$city.'<br>';
    $body .= 'Postalcode:'.$postalcode.'<br>';
    $body .= 'Address:'.$address.'<br>';



$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\nReply-To: " . $from . "";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {

  echo("<p>Sent</p>");
 } else {
  echo("<p>Error...</p>");
 }
?>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="div1" class="fluid"><!-- header ends here-->
    <div id="header" class="fluid">
      <div class="fluid logo_container zeroMargin_tablet">
      <div class="fluid logo_mvc"></div>
      <!-- logo_mvc ends here-->
      <div class="fluid logo_gsm"></div>
      <!-- logo_gsm ends here-->
    </div>
    <!-- logo_container ends here-->
</div>
    <div class="fluid imageslide zeroMargin_desktop">
      <div class="fluid imageslide_gs zeroMargin_desktop"></div>
      <!-- imageslide_gs ends here-->
      <div class="fluid imageslide_content">
      <h1>IP Product Introduction and VoIP PBX
Appliance Training Day @ Toronto</h1>
      </div><!-- imageslide_content ends here-->
      <div class="fluid imageslide_product"></div>
      <!-- imageslide_product ends here-->
    </div><!-- imageslide ends here-->
    <div class="fluid content">
    <div class="fluid content_det">
    <h3>Event information</h3>
    <p>Please join us at the Fairfield Inn & Suites Toronto Airport where Grandstream will offer four different sessions during the day. </p>
    <h3>Introduction to Grandstream IP products</h3>
    <p><b>8:45am - 10:15am</b><br/>
Introduction to Grandstream, and basic information on Grandstream products including ATAs, gateways, routers and telephones. </p>
<h3>Introduction to IP cameras IP and Surveillance products</h3>
    <p><b>12:45pm - 2:15pm</b><br/>
Basic information on IP cameras and surveillance products, and the introduction of the brand new GVR3550 Network Video Recorder. </p>
<h3>Advanced Technical Training for UCM VoIP PBX's</h3>
    <p><b>2:30pm - 4:30pm</b><br/>
This session will focus on the advanced features of the UCM series, including the new features of the upcoming software and the brand new UCM6510 VoIP PBX for T1 networks. </p>
    </div><!-- content_det ends here--><div class="fluid contet_form">

    <h2>Register Now</h2>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>First name *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name Here" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>

    </div>


    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Company Name *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="cname" placeholder="Enter Your Company Name Here" value="<?php echo $cname; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $cnameErr;?></span></div>

    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Mobile Number *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="mobileno" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number Here" value="<?php echo $mobileno; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $mobilenoErr?></span>
     </div>

    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Email Id *:</b></label>
    <input type="email" size="20px" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id Here" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr?></span></div>


    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>City *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="city" placeholder="Enter Your City Name Here" value="<?php echo $city;?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $cityErr?></span></div>

    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Postal Code *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="postalcode" placeholder="Enter Postal Code Here" value="<?php echo $postalcode; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $postalcodeErr?></span>
     </div>

    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Address *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="address" placeholder="Enter Address Here" value="<?php echo $address; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $addressErr?></span></div>


<button name="submit" >Submit</button>
    </form>

    </div><!-- contet_form ends here-->
    </div><!-- content ends here-->
  </div><!-- div1 ends here-->
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @sandeep again new problem?

Comment: @Yes, any suggestions or answers

Comment: Yes Ofcourse I will provide now check with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this if

```
if(!empty($name)&& !empty($cname)&&!empty($mobileno)&& !empty($email)&&!empty($city)&&!empty($postalcode)&&!empty($address)){
```

and place

```
 if(!empty($_POST['name'])&& !empty($_POST['cname'])&&!empty($_POST['mobileno'])&& !empty($_POST['email'])&&!empty($_POST['city'])&&!empty($_POST['postalcode'])&&!empty($_POST['address'])){


            $to = 'sskumbar7@gmail.com';

            $subject = 'I need to show html'; 

            $from ='sandeep.sk@microvillage.in'; 
            ini_set("sendmail_from", $from);
                $name=$_POST['name'];
                $cname=$_POST['cname'];
                $mobileno=$_POST['mobileno'];
                $email=$_POST['email'];
                $city=$_POST['city'];
                $postalcode=$_POST['postalcode'];
                $address=$_POST['address'];
            $headers = "From: " .$from. "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from. "\r\n";
                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;  charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
                $body ='User Name:'.$name.'<br>';
                $body .= 'Company Name:'.$cname.'<br>';
                $body .= 'Mobile Numbaer:'.$mobileno.'<br>';
                $body .= 'Email Id:'.$email.'<br>';
                $body .= 'City:'.$city.'<br>';
                $body .= 'Postalcode:'.$postalcode.'<br>';
                $body .= 'Address:'.$address.'<br>';
            $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\nReply-To: " . $from . "";
              $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {

  echo("<p>Sent</p>");
 } else {
  echo("<p>Error...</p>");
 }

   header('Location: Submission.php?submit=1');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

move following variable from if condition and put them above if condition

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$cname=$_POST['cname'];
$mobileno=$_POST['mobileno'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$postalcode=$_POST['postalcode'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
```

and replace `if(isset($name)){`

with `if(!empty($name)){`

Comment: if i do that , i am not at all getting any mail